# Trouble Opening a Fluorescent Light Fixture

Tags: lighting, ceiling, troubleshooting

My house has an old fluorescent ceiling fixture in the kitchen that probably dates back to a remodel done in the 1980s.  The bulbs have gone out and I am having trouble figuring out how to open the fixture to replace the bulbs.

The frame is metal and the three individual light panels are plastic

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Tell us what you have tried so we know what not to suggest.

Answer (score 2):

It is bit difficult to tell from the picture.

Often on those older florescent fixtures the plastic panels have a integral plastic flange on their top edge that supports them- they basically hang inside the metal frame. So they drop in from the top- inside the fixture. To remove them lift up on the plastic and carefully flex and rotate them to get them out. If your fixture is real old then the plastic may have become more brittle and care should be taken not to damage them.